# How do I get modals to work similarly to they used to?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I just pulled some code that I had worked on a few months back using angular and bootstrap or more specifically that uses modals.  Apparently modals have changed quite a bit.

My code:

```
        <div class="modal" ng-show="isDocPopupVisible">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="closeDocPopup()">×</button>
                <h3>{{selectedDoc.name}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <strong>Created Date:</strong> {{selectedDoc.date}} <br />
                <br />
                <p>
                    <span style="white-space:pre">{{selectedDoc.description}}</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="{{selectedDoc.href}}" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="closeDocPopup()">Download</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn" ng-click="closeDocPopup()">Close</a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Nothing happens anymore when I click a doc.  If I change the class from modal to modal-dialog, the bottom slides down, but I can't get it to be a popout modal anymore.  Reviewing bootstrap's docs makes it seem much more intense than it used to be, which I guess is fine, but I'm just hoping it's something similar to the btn btn switched to btn btn-primary.

Any help - thanks all.

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/migration/#notes

Answer (score 0):

but I figured it out, just had to switch some things up.

```
                   <tr ng-repeat="doc in docs.cast | orderBy:'name' | filter:search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#docModal" ng-click="showDocPopup(doc)">
                        <td>{{doc.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{doc.date}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="docModal" role="dialog" ng-show="isDocPopupVisible">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="closeDocPopup()">×</button>
                        <h3>{{selectedDoc.name}}</h3>
                    </div>
```